# Number of lines of code per dataset in Reort Builder 3.0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

How many lines of code does report builder 3.0 handle per data? is it 757? 
It seem i can not add more lines of code, what is the work around ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping the SQL in the data set, convert this to a stored procedure then use the **Stored Procedure** option for the query type.  See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/dataset-properties-dialog-box-query-report-builder?view=sql-server-2017) for more details on this.  Using a stored procedure will bring additional benefits, such query plan reuse, an extra layer of security, and efficient reuse of the same stored procedure for other reports that would be using an identical SQL query.